# form submission to an iframe which is in another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

As stated in the title, I'd like to submit a form and the result is shown in an iFrame that is in another file.

**file1.html**

```
<form action="login.php" target="target_iframe">
   <input type="text" id="login_id" />
   <input type="text" id="login_ps" />
   <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**file2.html**

```
<iframe src="login.php" name="target_iframe"></iframe>
```

Please note that file "login.php" is another file from 3rd party, and that's why I am thinking to embed them into iframe.

P.S. The whole idea was to submit log in information and sure the result in another page that still featuring my own header and footer. And this is why I came up the idea to embed result page into iframe. However, I'm very open with this, and welcome other solution for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you doing a get or post request?

Comment: You forgot to add the `method` attribute to your `form` tag. And, is the currently solution not working besides that?

Comment: @AhsN by default `method` is `get`

Comment: @zazu basically, in typical case, after submission, the information go to login.php. And it is the same for my case, however, the login.php are framed into file2.html. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: how are you loading file2.html? why dont you put the `iframe` in file1.html?

Comment: @zazu in my case, login form is in header.php, and I wanna achieve no matter whichever page it is, when the login information are submitted, it will jump to file2.html with login.php embeded in body section.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<form action="login.php" target="target_iframe">
   <input type="text" id="login_id" />
   <input type="text" id="login_ps" />
   <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
</form>
```

to this (f1.html):

```
<form method="GET" action="login.php" target="target_iframe">
   <input type="text" id="login_id" name="login_id"/>
   <input type="text" id="login_ps" name="login_ps" />
   <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
</form>
```

The problem was that you forgot to put `name` attribute to your form inputs. Only inputs having a `name` attribute within the form is *submitted*.

My test php file, **login.php**:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

**f1.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="GET" action="f2.php">
        <input type="text" id="login_id" name="login_id"/>
        <input type="text" id="login_ps" name="login_ps" />
        <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="Login" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**f1.php:**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET["login_id"]) && isset($_GET["login_ps"])){
?>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <form id="myform" action="login.php" target="target_iframe" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="login_id" value="<?= $_GET['login_id'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="login_ps" value="<?= $_GET['login_ps'] ?>">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#myform").submit();
        });
        </script>
    <?php }?>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="target_iframe" name="target_iframe" width="500" height="500" ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for that. But this was not what I want. In this case, it will pop up a new window instead of going to f2.html and show the result in login.php, which is in the iframe.